# Early version of Wolfenstein 3D

Tags: wolfenstein-3d

[Wikipedia on Wolfenstein 3D development mentioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfenstein_3D#Development), that *"... **early concept** of the game included some innovative stealth concepts—dragging dead bodies, swapping uniforms with fallen guards, silent attacks"*. It seems very interesting. Reason for not having it here was, that it *"drastically slowed the game down and made the controls complicated"*.

Is it possible to obtain it, or see this version somewhere on the internet - videos or playable version would be best ... Thank You very much. :)

(I wonder if I should contact the developers about it, but perhaps this version is out - so I am asking there.)

Answer (score 7):

An "early concept" doesn't mean it was "publicly available".

Most likely it was one of the alpha/prototype versions built during the development of Wolf3D and was never released outside iD Software offices.

Most likely it was built, and then John Carmack and other employees played it, and it was rejected. Then those (incomplete) features were removed.

It is worth noting that such version was probably very incomplete, probably with placeholder graphics, incomplete controls and maybe even without a menu. It was intended only for developers, and not for the final user. Maybe it wasn't even "playable", but more as a test/proof-of-concept.